# Jest returning error when calling mockReturnValueOnce with jest.spyOn()

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

```
jest --passWithNoTests --silent --noStackTrace --runInBand --watch -c jest-unit-config.js
```

[Project repo](https://github.com/ericsj/clean-ts-api/)

Error in jest.spyOn(bcrypt, 'hash').mockRejectedValue(new Error('Async error message'))

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'Error' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
> 31     jest.spyOn(bcrypt, 'hash').mockRejectedValue(new Error('Async error message'))

```
    import bcrypt from 'bcrypt'
    import { BcryptAdapter } from './bcrypt-adapter'

    jest.mock('bcrypt', () => ({
      async hash (): Promise<string> {
        return 'hash'
      }
    }))
    const salt = 12
    const makeSut = (): BcryptAdapter => {
      return new BcryptAdapter(salt)
    }
    
    describe('Bcrypt Adapter', () => `{`
    
      test('Should throw if bcrypt throws', async () => {
        const sut = makeSut()
        jest.spyOn(bcrypt, 'hash').mockRejectedValue(new Error('Async error message'))
        const promise = sut.encrypt('any_value')
        await expect(promise).rejects.toThrow()
      })
    })
```

If I use .mockImplementantion instead of .mockRejectedValue, another error occurs:

```
  test('Should throw if bcrypt throws', async () => {
    const sut = makeSut()
    jest.spyOn(bcrypt, 'hash').mockImplementation((): Promise<any> => { Promise.reject(new Error()) })
    const promise = sut.encrypt('any_value')
    await expect(promise).rejects.toThrow()
  })
```

> error TS2355: A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor
> 'any' must return a value.
> 31 jest.spyOn(bcrypt, 'hash').mockImplementation((): Promise => { Promise.reject(new Error()) })

BcryptAdapter.encrypt

```
  async encrypt (value: string): Promise<string> {
    const hash = await bcrypt.hash(value, this.salt)
    return hash
  }
```

Package version:

> ```
>     "@types/jest": "^27.5.0",
>     "jest": "^28.1.0",
>     "ts-jest": "^28.0.2",
>     "typescript": "^4.6.4"
> ```
>
> node v16.14.0

I know there is a workaround using `.mockImplementation((): never => {throw new Error()})` but the question here is why the first two approaches didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Could you help remove this code

```
jest.mock('bcrypt', () => ({
    async hash (): Promise<string> {
       return 'hash'
    }
}))
```

because you use jest.spyOn to mock it return Error instead of `string`. Also I think we dont need jest.mock when using jest.spyOn here

Comment: When i use .mockRejectedValueOnce('error') I get the error "TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.". Jest.mock is needed because the script also has tests for success cases, in which return values are not mocked